# Is there a way to add to a variable across threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, python-2.7

Is there a way that I can have a single variable across active threads like below

```
count = 0
threadA(count)
threadB(count)

threadA(count):
    #do stuff
    count += 1
threadB(count):
    #do stuff
    print count
```

so that count will print out 1? I changed the variable in thread A and it reflected across to the other thread?

Comment: I'll assume you've left out the actual thread creation for conciseness, but it would seem the biggest problem here is that you are hiding the global variable with a parameter of your functions. That is, threadA modifies its parameter and not the global.

Comment: Hmm yes that is it. so if i do not pass count in as a parameter than when i add the 1 to count in threadA count will then be 1 and then when it prints inside threadB it will print 1? whereas if i pass it in the scope changes to just the thread?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `count` is already available to all your threads.  But you need to synchronize access to it, or you will lose updates.  Look into using a lock to protect access to the count.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am just reading about multithreading with the Thread Module so Ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use processes instead of threads, use `multiprocessing`. It has more features, including having a `Manager` objects which handles shared objects for you. As a perk, you can share objects across machines!

### source

```
import multiprocessing, signal, time

def producer(objlist):
    '''
    add an item to list every sec
    '''
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return
        msg = 'ding: {:04d}'.format(int(time.time()) % 10000)
        objlist.append( msg )
        print msg


def scanner(objlist):
    '''
    every now and then, consume objlist & run calculation
    '''
    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return
        print 'items: {}'.format( list(objlist) )
        objlist[:] = []


def main():

    # create obj sharable between all processes
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    my_objlist = manager.list() # pylint: disable=E1101

    multiprocessing.Process(
        target=producer, args=(my_objlist,),
    ).start()

    multiprocessing.Process(
        target=scanner, args=(my_objlist,),
    ).start()

    # kill everything after a few seconds
    signal.signal(
        signal.SIGALRM, 
        lambda _sig,_frame: manager.shutdown(),
        )
    signal.alarm(12)

    try:
        manager.join() # wait until both workers die
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```